# Como faço para achar os valores singulares de uma matriz?

Tags: matlab

Como faço para achar os valores singulares de uma matriz no MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Para obter os valores singulares de uma matriz pode fazer o seguinte:

```
v = svds(SuaMatriz);
```

Esta função calcula os seis maiores valores singulares da matriz, assim como os vectores associados.

Se necessitar de mais ou menos valores singulares pode utilizar:

```
v = svds(SuaMatriz, NumeroDeValoresSingulares);
```

Mais informação [aqui](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/svds.html).